# Create a String/Query String from RouteValueDictionary Object

Tags: c#, urlhelper

I have created `UrlHelper` extension function(s) for different use(s). Now I am creating a function which will accept three parameters like:

```
url.cutomAction(action, controller, new RouteValueDictionary{{key,value},{..},.. });
```

In an extension function I will take the `RouteValueDictionary` and iterate over it like this :

```
foreach (var data in RouteData)
{
    data.Key, data.Value.ToString();
}
```

But now I need to know that while iterating over these keys and values how can I generate a string or query string like:

```
(key = value, key1 = value1, key2 = value2, ...)
```

so I can create a final URL and pass this string in it like:

```
return helper.Action(action, controller, new {above_Generated_string})
```

Or whatever is the right way to do it.

Comment: `Url.Action` takes `RouteValueDictionary` as one of it parameters, why do you create a new extension method?

Comment: Yes, I know. Reason to create the extension method is to create the string/query string of own choice. E.g. using the extension method I can create string like key=value|key1=value1 etc. I know using the pipe as separator does not make a sense but I placed it there just for an example.

Comment: If you will create such a string (which is not a big deal) how will you pass it to the `Url.Action`? It doesn't have a third string parameter?

Comment: I will take care of "that" thrid parameter. What i want to know is how to create the string while looping through it. And as I mentioned I am not good at all in C# so I do not know how to proceed with it. Shall I create some string list or shall I use string class function or string builder etc....

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways you can do it. One of them is using LINQ:

```
var result = RouteData.Select(s => string.Format("{0}={1}", s.Key, s.Value))
.Aggregate((current, next) => string.Format("{0}|{1}", current, next));
```